# Having trouble with getImage method when extending BannerComponent

Tags: spartacus-storefront

how are you?

I'm trying to customize the BannerComponent, so I extended the class as shown below.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { BannerComponent } from '@spartacus/storefront';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-small-banner',
  templateUrl: './small-banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./small-banner.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class SmallBannerComponent extends BannerComponent {}
```

I don't have a modules for the custom banner, I have one a level above where I centralize all the imports for the child components of this structures, an this module looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CmsConfig, ConfigModule, SiteContextModule } from '@spartacus/core';
import {
  MediaModule,
  OutletModule,
  PageSlotModule,
} from '@spartacus/storefront';
import { SmallBannerComponent } from './small-banner/small-banner.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SmallBannerComponent],
  bootstrap: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OutletModule,
    PageSlotModule,
    SiteContextModule,
    MediaModule,
    ConfigModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        BannerComponent: {
          component: SmallBannerComponent,
        },
      },
    } as CmsConfig),
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

The template for the custom banner looks like this at the moment:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">

  <h3>{{ data.headline }}</h3>
  <p>{{ data.content }}</p>
  <cx-media [container]="getImage(data.media.url)"></cx-media>
 
</ng-container>
```

If I use like in the original template, getImage(data), also does not work.
The headline and content have rendered fine, but when I try to render the image using the cx-media, it breaks. If I remove the method getImage(), it loads "fine" and stops breaking the whole website.

`<cx-media [container]="data.media.url"></cx-media>`

[Loading the data fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ds9K.png)

The method getTarget is working fine.

Could anyone help me with this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The thing is that the template in the documentation is not up to date. The version of Spartacus that I'm using doesn't have the getImage method anymore.

And to add, I made a mistake when trying to load the data, where I tried to load only the url, and this was not rendering the image properly.

So if you change the line

```
<cx-media [container]="getImage(data)"></cx-media>
```

to

```
<cx-media [container]="data.media"></cx-media>
```

it works like a charm.